# How to set wartchpoint of property of category via lldv

Tags: properties, categories, lldb

I'm debugging a problem of AVPlayer.(The currentItem of AVPlayer was set to NULL when running).

So i want to set a watchpoint to the currentItem to find where it was changed.

But the error happen:

```
(lldb) watchpoint set variable self->_audioPlayer->_currentItem
error: "_currentItem" is not a member of "(AVPlayer *) self->_audioPlayer"
```

I've checked "AVPlayer.h":

```
@interface AVPlayer (AVPlayerItemControl)

/* indicates the current item of the player */
@property (nonatomic, readonly) AVPlayerItem *currentItem;
```

So the problem is how to set such watchpoint, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that the `currentItem` property is not synthesized by an instance variable,
or that the declaration of the instance variable is invisible to the debugger.

You could try to set a *breakpoint* on the property *setter method* instead:

```
breakpoint set -n "-[AVPlayer setCurrentItem:]"
```

Comment: Because currentItem is a readonly property, so couldn't use the command above.  But i found it's ok to break like this:b -[AVPlayer _setCurrentItem:]